# How are the weights in the LSTMCell unit initialized in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the [LSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell) unit in my network and I can not figure out just how the weights for this unit is initialized.

I've tried diving in the code from method to method, but I am not 100% sure how all this code works.

In the LSTMCell source code, the following lines seems to initialize the weights. From [contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2c5a65b9b3cae3f08f32715712bd7b59877fcaf6/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py#L394-L395):

```
    [...]
    scope = vs.get_variable_scope()
    with vs.variable_scope(scope, initializer=self._initializer) as unit_scope:
        [...]
```

The method `variable_scope` and how scopes are defined also confuses me, and I am unsure how this logic works.

From [python/ops/variable_scope.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2c5a65b9b3cae3f08f32715712bd7b59877fcaf6/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py), the method [`variable_scope`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2c5a65b9b3cae3f08f32715712bd7b59877fcaf6/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py#L1413) seem to call the method [`_pure_variable_scope`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2c5a65b9b3cae3f08f32715712bd7b59877fcaf6/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py#L1254), which in turn seem to return an instance of [`VariableScope`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2c5a65b9b3cae3f08f32715712bd7b59877fcaf6/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py#L770) which finally seem to call [`get_variable`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2c5a65b9b3cae3f08f32715712bd7b59877fcaf6/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py#L1037). The [docstring](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2c5a65b9b3cae3f08f32715712bd7b59877fcaf6/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py#L1071-L1074) for `get_variable` reads as follows:

> If initializer is `None` (the default), the default initializer passed
>   in the variable scope will be used. If that one is `None` too, a
>   `glorot_uniform_initializer` will be used. The initializer can also be
>   a Tensor, in which case the variable is initialized to this value and
>   shape.

Is it then correct that unless no initializer is specified, the LSTMCell will be initialized with `glorot_uniform_initializer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your tracing of the code, I believe that you are correct: an LSTMCell will be initialized with `glorot_uniform_initializer`, also known as the `Xavier uniform initializer`, whose implementation is found at:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/38e0922d1e2dcd572379af4496f878492e9f689a/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L553